# How to prevent command-arrow keys from navigating macOS Chrome forward/backward?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

On macOS, I commonly use the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>left arrow</kbd> or <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>right arrow</kbd> shortcuts to move the cursor to the start or end of text.

Unfortunately, if I do this in Chrome desktop web browser app, and the keyboard focus accidentally escapes whatever text field, then the browser will navigate forward or backward in history.

I only expect <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> keyboard shortcuts to navigate history.

What's the simplest (preferably avoiding third-party apps) way to do this (something in `chrome://`, perhaps)?

Comment: Probably an add-on / extension? Or Chromium might give you the source code to edit out the offending short-cuts

Comment: I wish you luck, but I don't think that's Chrome-specific. Safari does it too & has no menu item showing it that could be overridden. The menu shows Cmd [ or ] for navigation, but arrows just do it too if no text area is in focus.

Comment: I see now Firefox also does this. Reminds me of the formerly universal, now-abandoned behavior of the delete key navigating browsers backward in history.

Comment: Map those shortcuts onto another menu function that has a benign result if accidentally triggered.

Comment: If I map these shortcuts to random/benign commands, it would prevent the backward/forward navigation, but it would also lose the native home/end behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the code, you can trap the key shortcut for the page:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if ( ( e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey )
      && e.keyCode == 37 ) // left arrow key.
  {
         e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> in a text field; those should safely do what you want!

Comment: I didn't realize this was possible, thank you. However, command-arrow is (1) easier to press, given location of the keys; and (2) command-arrow (to move by line) is easily used instead of, or in conjunction with, option-arrow (to move by word) and arrow (to move by character).