# Disable Alt + Left to navigate back in Firefox

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, history

In Firefox 85 the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left arrow</kbd> shortcut causes it to navigate back in browsing history. It does this *even when a text field is focused and typed in* which is just too much of a bad design for me, to put it mildly (it's more like Design to Error than Design for Error).

This happens in both **Windows 10** and in **Ubuntu 20.10** as far as I know. The only time it doesn't happen? In **macOS**, when the same shortcut is set on a system level to make the caret jump to the next word.

If I make a single mistake while using the arrow keys to navigate in any simple text field on the web, I lose everything I spent the last 10 minutes typing.

**I want these shortcuts gone from Firefox. How is that accomplished?**

#### Related questions

- [Same issue for Chrome on macOS](https://superuser.com/questions/1367750/how-to-prevent-command-arrow-keys-from-navigating-macos-chrome-forward-backward)

Comment: I don't think it's possible without an add-on/extension. Try [Shortkeys (Custom Keyboard Shortcuts) for Firefox – Get this Extension for  Firefox (en-US)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/shortkeys/)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you for the suggestion, I'll have a look. It's weird how the only types of apps with proper keybinding facilities seem to be games, video players and IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the add-on
[Shortkeys](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/shortkeys/)
but didn't manage to make it work for
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>.

I therefore used the free and versatile
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following script nullifies this key-combination when the active window
has "Firefox" in its title:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinActive, Firefox
!Left::return
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Comment: Thanks for trying the extension out. That's a good idea for Windows. I was hoping for some Firefox pref, but in the absence of that maybe it has to be overridden on an OS level. I guess I should try creating global shortcuts in Ubuntu in the same vein.

Comment: You could try Shortkeys yourself, maybe it will work in your environment.